# Conditional elements in a Python Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, imblearn

I was wondering if it is possible to have a pipeline with mandatory elements and optional ones. And the optional ones are conditional. For example, that you can have a pipeline with downsampling element or you can have the same pipeline without downsampling. So

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as IMBPipeline
import xgboost as xgb
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler 

pipe = IMBPipeline([
                         ('sampling',RandomUnderSampler()),
                         ('clf', xgb.XGBClassifier(**params, n_jobs=-1))
                        ])
```

and you only have the sampling part if you have an imbalanced dataset for example. But the sampling part is still in the pipeline, just conditional. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this functionality does not exist. However, for this specific question, you can just always run the undersampling and if your dataset is not imbalanced, the undersampler will simply have no effect (or very little).